# What's the difference between Stabilizer() block and enable_self_stabilization parameter?

Tags: cntk

When should I use one or another? Tutorials and examples use either `Sequential([Stabilizer(), Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim))])` or `LSTMP_component_with_self_stabilization` from Examples/common/nn.py. I've tried replacing the former with `Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim, enable_self_stabilization=True))` in the char_rnn.py example, but the results are significantly worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Stabilizer` layer multiplies its input with a learnable scalar. This simple trick has been shown to significantly improve convergence and stability. It has some similarity with `BatchNormalization`. Generally, when you can use `BatchNormalization`, you should try that first. Where that is not possible, which is specifically inside recurrent loops, I recommend to use `Stabilizer` instead.

Normally, you must inject it explicitly in your model. A special case are the recurrent step functions (e.g. `LSTM`), which include `Stabilizer`s inside. Use `enable_self_stabilization=True` to enable that. Those built-in `Stabilizer`s only apply to internal variables. For the main input, you must insert a `Stabilizer` yourself.

If you include explicit `Stabilizer`s but set `enable_self_stabilization=False` (e.g. as a `default_option`), then those explicit `Stabilizer`s are no-ops.

It is not my experience that `Stabilizer` makes things worse. It is generally a sure-fire thing to improve convergence. It does change numeric ranges, though. So if it makes convergence worse, I suggest to experiment with different hyper-parameter settings, e.g. reduce the learning rate.